# determine the analytic function $f$ such that $|f|=(x^2 +y^2)e^x$

Tags: complex-analysis

Determine the analytic function $f$ such that $|f|=(x^2 +y^2)e^x$

I know that for $f=(u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ then $f$ is analytic if

$$u_x=v_y$$

and $$u_y=-v_x$$

For this question, I'm given $|f|$, can I assume that $|f|= \sqrt{u^2+v^2}$?

If I can do that, then $u^2 + v^2 =(x^2+y^2)^2 e^{2x}$. I intend to find $u_x, u_y$ or $v_x,v_y$ then use the integral to find $u$ and $v$. But how do I know which is $u$ and which is in $v$. I wonder if anyone would give  a hint please.

Comment: Hint: $|e^z|=e^{\text{Re}z}$.

Comment: I know that for $z=x+iy$ I can rewite it as $e^z=e^x(\cos y +i \sin y)$, so $|e^z|=e^x$, but I still can't see the relation to my function. Can you give a little more hint please.

Comment: Second hint: what familiar analytic function has $x^2 + y^2 = |z|^2$ as norm?

Comment: The product of two analytic functions is analytic, correct? Is there a product that when you take the modulus you get $|f|$?

Comment: $|z|^2 =z \overline z$ oh, so $|f|=|z|^2|e^z|=|z^2e^z|$ so $f=z^2 e^z=(x^2 -y^2+2ixy)(e^x)(\cos y+ i \sin y)$? From this I can show the Cauchy Reimann equation is true, right?

Comment: Also, if the two functions of $f$ are entire, you don't need to check the CR conditions.

Comment: Got it, thanks guys.